# Class App\Http\Controllers\EditareProfilController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am very new in Laravel and this is my first project. I have this problem and I don`t know how to fix it.

[This is my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1RoP.jpg)

I am sure I have tried all I know

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EditareProfilController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $tasdhis->middlewasdare('auasdth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return vasdasdiew('editaasdasdasdeprofil');
    }
}
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::get('/editarasdasdeprofil', 'EditareProfilasdasdasdontroller@index')->name('editarepasdasdasdrofil');
```

Comment: ```composer dump-autoload```

Comment: Your controller is in Auth folder. You must place your controller file in Controllers folder

Comment: Thanks Muhamad, but is a Profile page, it has to be in auth folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location for controllers is **app\Http\Controllers** if you add a folder just add it to your route in order to laravel localize it. In your code you are storing your controller under the Auth folder.

Update your route to:

```
Route::get('/editareprofil', 'Auth\EditareProfilController@index')->name('editareprofil');
```

And also don't forget to update the namespace.

```
namespace App\Http\Controlllers\FOLDER;
```

Comment: Also, you should update your namespace `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth; `